# What's the real difference between klassoop and instanceklass?

Tags: jvm

I saw one of them is described as "An instanceKlass is the VM level representation of a Java class." , another is " A klassOop is the C++ equivalent of a Java class. " , so what's the difference between them? Why we need both of them , can we combine  two to one ?
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/hotspot/file/ba66650acf63/src/share/vm/oops/instanceKlass.hpp
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/hotspot/file/ba66650acf63/src/share/vm/oops/klassOop.hpp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be more accurate to compare `klassOop` vs. `Klass`, since `instanceKlass` is a particular descendant of `Klass`.

In JDK 7 class metadata was stored in Permanent Generation of Java Heap. Like all objects in Java Heap class metadata had an object header. `klassOop` was basically a wrapper that wraps C++ `Klass` object into Java Heap object (also known as OOP).

```
     _________________
    |                 |
    | mark_word       |  <-- OOP header
    | klass_field     |
    | _______________ |
    ||               ||
    || C++ vtbl ptr  ||  <-- InstanceKlass data
    || subtype cache ||
    || instance size ||
    || java mirror   ||
    || super         ||
    || access_flags  ||
    || name          ||
    || ...           ||
    ||_______________||
    |_________________|
```

Since JDK 8 there is no more Permanent Generation and there is no more `klassOop` entity. All class metadata is stored in Metaspace as normal C++ objects.

If you want to study HotSpot JVM internals, I suggest to look into [`jdk8u`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/) repository instead.